# Javascript + Promise +await +async -- variable undefined

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I am getting undefined at line 123. I think its something to do with the way I use promise/await and async due to the single threaded feature of JS.

Any thoughts to get this fixed. please comment

Warm Regards
Kdm

[image]

---

### [image]
//

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as code instead of as a image. Reduce your code to the minimum needed to reproduce the issue, (though is must be enough to reproduce the issue)

Comment: Post also seems to be missing the error text

Comment: You are running an async IIFE without awaiting it. I imagine you did that because you were trying to use `await` without changing your original function to `async` (I can't think of other reasons), but it won't work as you thought in this situation.